# Return customer to same position when clicking browser's back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, browser-history

**What I am trying to do?**
I want to remember the current position of the user on the page, so once s/he navigates to another page and then comes back using the browser "Back" button to scroll to that position. Please note that I need to maintain this behaviour only when the user clicks on the browser back button.

**How I am trying to achieve it?**
When the user clicks on an href I was using a method to replace the state. The page was then re-directed to the right place.

```
window.history.replaceState({ scrollToProduct: true, productCode: 'produt-XXXX' }, document.title, `${window.location.href}?product-code=produt-XXXX`);
```

I was then trying to register popstate listener in my App.vue

```
beforeMount() {
        window.onpopstate = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        };
    }
```

Where my issue is?
Unfortunatelly the popstate listener doesn't get attached, so I can't capture the click of the "Back" button.

I've also tried using router.push.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'NameOfComponent' });
```

What is interesting is that I get navigated to the other page (without page reload), and when I click on the back buttton the popstate does work. I am unfortunatelly not able to pass anything into the hisotry state.

Can someone help with this?

PS: I am not using SPA, but rather refresh on each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use vue-router if you don't register it correctly or if you don't use Vue as an SPA.

What you need is history.back() or history.go(-1).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back